# Trying Ubuntu Using Live CD

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I'm debating installing Ubuntu alongside W7 on my laptop so I can familiarize myself with that OS. I'd like to try Ubuntu first, and play a bit with the UI. I burned a Ubuntu live CD so that I can boot from CD and try that OS without actually installing it and without making any permanent changes to my current config, but I wanted to ask if there are any potential issues?

Any way booting to Ubuntu using the CD might somehow harm my current system/OS, or can I go right back to business as usual without any changes once I remove the CD?

Comment: "If you are a beginner, LiLi will let you try Linux for the first time, keeping Windows clean of any modifications." http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booting from the Ubuntu Live CD is completely harmless. Yes, you can go right back to your current system/OS after you remove the CD.

Just make sure that you select *"Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer"* in the boot up screen and that you **don't** click on the *"Install"* icon on the desktop.